# How i can define a Bind Include list for an object, if i am passing the object as a parameter to my edit action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, model-binding

i want to handling concurrency access to my ASP.NET MVC web application, so i have added `timestamp` annotation to my class as follow:-

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(Assessment_Validation))]
 [Bind(Include = "Date, Title")]
    public partial class Assessment {}
```

&

```
public class Assessment_Validation : IValidatableObject 
    { public DateTime Date { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = " Assessment Title is Rquired")]
            public String Title { get; set; }

            [Timestamp]
            public Byte[] Timestamp { get; set; } }
```

Then on the Action method i have included the folloiwng :-

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Assessment a)
        {            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid) 
                {
                    elearningrepository.UpdateAssessment(a);
                    elearningrepository.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = a.AssessmentID });
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                var clientValues = (Assessment)entry.Entity;

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit was" 
                 + "modified by another user after you got the original value.");
                               }
            catch (DataException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
            }       
            return View(a);}
```

and finally the  `elearningrepository.UpdateAssessment(a)`:-

```
 public void UpdateAssessment(Assessment a)
        {
            entities1.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

The above will always return an `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` even if no two users edit the same object, i think this is related to the `[Bind(Include = "Date, Title")]` on the partial class. So how i can pass an object as a argument in the edit action method and at the same time define a `Bind` list for the object?. 
The problme also if i update my action method (to not have an object as a parameter) as  following:- , then the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` will never be raised !!!!:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            Assessment a = elearningrepository.GetAssessment(id);
                           try
            {
                if (TryUpdateModel(a))
                {
                    elearningrepository.UpdateAssessment(a);
                    elearningrepository.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = a.AssessmentID });
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                var clientValues = (Assessment)entry.Entity;

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit was" 
                 + "modified by another user after you got the original value.");
            }
            catch (DataException)
            {                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
            }return View(a);
```

so how i can solve this problme ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decorating the model property with the [Timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.timestampattribute) attribute?